# C++ const method compile error in struct when accessing data in member unordered_map

Tags: c++, methods, constants, unordered-map

I don't understand the compile error I'm getting. Below is a simplified example of my use-case.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

#using namespace std;

struct C{
    unordered_map<int, string> m;

    C(){
        m[1] = "one";
        m[2] = "two";
    }

    int method() const{
        const string s = m[2];
        return 42;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    cout << c.method() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Below are the requirements for my use-case:

- I'd like the method `method()` to be `const`, because I'm sure it won't change any member field.
- The member field `m` should be an `unordered_map` (or any hash table) due to frequent data access.

The above code fails to compile with `error: passing ‘const std::unordered_map<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`. However, if I remove the `const` from the method `method()` (which I do not want to, or cannot, do), the code compiles fine. What am I not understanding? Is there no way of making the method `const` in my use-case?

By the way, I'm using GCC 5.2.1 with CLion 1.2.4 on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::unordered_map::operator[]
```

is not a `const` method as it inserts elements if not present. So you cannot use it on your constant `m`. Use

```
std::unordered_map::at
```

instead.

Comment: Bet _you_ won't get a mega backlash (e.g. being accused of "abuse") for "getting in a few upvotes before dupehammering", [the way I did](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313467/560648). Life can be so unfair!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did mention another lookup method that is only present in the comments over there. ;) But seriously, if this answer violates site rules, they can go complain to a mod, otherwise, tough luck for people who don't like this. I won't engage in any meta wars.

Comment: Perfect answer thank you.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I couldn't agree more! Sadly, in my case they did, and what follows was downvote-hammering and mod deletion of the answer. Pfft.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Meta police gonna do what meta police gonna do. vOv